# How to create an edit button work properly in CRUD?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm doing CRUD project, overall my code was work. But just one of my code cannt work properly that is edit button.

```
$("editable.btn-primary").click(function(){
      $(".table").find('tr').eq(this.value).each(function(){
        $("#username").val($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
        $("#password").val($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
        $(".btn-info").val($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
      });
      $(".btn-info").attr("name", "edit");
    });
```

I expect the data can editable and update when user click on edit button

Comment: can you explain more , it's not clair

Answer (score 0):

May be the editable button dynamically generated elements.

Also check if editable is a class, you need change to `.editable.btn-primary`

```
$(document).on('click','editable.btn-primary',function(){
      $(".table").find('tr').eq(this.value).each(function(){
        $("#username").val($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
        $("#password").val($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
        $(".btn-info").val($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
      });
      $(".btn-info").attr("name", "edit");
    });
```